# c# zip file to user containing all directories?

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I have a function which zips files and downloads them to the users machine.

However, when it zips the files they are within a few folders.

For example if i want to zip a file called test.doc and it is in c:/document/the folder/test.doc

In the zipped folder there will be "document" folder and "the folder" too. I just want the document in there

here is my code...

```
 public FileStreamResult DownloadDocs()
    {
        MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(SettingManager.OnlineForms));
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
            string name = Server.MapPath(SettingManager.OnlineForms + fi.Name);
            zip.AddFile(name);
        }

        zip.Save(workStream);
        workStream.Position = 0;

        FileStreamResult fileResult = new FileStreamResult(workStream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip);
        fileResult.FileDownloadName = "OnlineForms.zip";

        return fileResult;
    }
```

Comment: For clarification. You gone some files like: C:\documents\moep\doc1.txt C:\documents\moep\doc2.txt C:\documents\foo\doc1.txt C:\documents\foo\doc2.txt and you want to flatten out the moep, foo and documents folder?

Comment: in the OnlineForms.zip folder in the end i just want the documents, none of the folder they are contained in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the line

```
Zip.AddFile(name);
```

to

```
Zip.AddFile(name, string.Empty);
```

Also you could avoid the call to get the fileinfo. The  array of file names should suffice.

Comment: There is an overload of AddFile that takes the name of the base directory for the archived files.

Comment: Good solution. But watch out for possible file name collisions in case you got files with the same names in different directories.

Comment: @Nitram The code above from the OP takes files from the same directory.